# Map nested json to java field without writing the container names

Tags: java, json, spring-boot, groovy, jackson

I have a rest endpoint that returns a 3 level nested json like this one:

```
 {
   "user":{
      "departament":{
         "departInfo":{
            "departName":"String"
         }
      }
   }
}
```

And I have a java/groovy class without the same 3 nested levels:

```
@JsonIgnorePropertires("ignoreUnknown = true")
class User(){
    String departName
}
```

When I am making a rest call using restTemplate:

```
User response = restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.GET,
                                      request, User.class)
```

jackson is not mapping the field departName (because it is not at the same nested level I guess) even with the json ignore properties. I have solved my issue with this code:

```
@JsonIgnorePropertires("ignoreUnknown = true")
class User(){
    String departName;

    @JsonProperty("department")
    private void mapDepartmentName(Map<String,Object department) {
        this.departName = ((Map<String,String>)department.get("departInfo")).get("departName");
    }
}
```

which is working perfectly fine but I don't really like it because I still need to write the container's names. Can I solve this somehow (it doesn't necessarily need to be with jackson) without explicitly writing the useless and unnecessary container nested jsons?
I want to avoid changing my code even if the container's names changes. The code is java/groovy.

Comment: Try json Path  `$..departName`

Comment: where exactly? in the map method? could u write some code

Comment: Why's this tagged [groovy] I can't see the groovy bit?

Comment: all the code above is groovy and I can use a groovy json solution if there is one.

Comment: Sorry, I was confused when you said _"java class without the same 3 nested levels"_

Comment: np, I have edited the question :)

Answer (score 1):

Having added JsonPath as a dependency (assuming Maven) :

```
 <dependency>
     <groupId>com.jayway.jsonpath</groupId>
     <artifactId>json-path</artifactId>
     <version>2.3.0</version>
 </dependency>
```

You just get the json string and process it using JsonPath:

```
String json = "...";
List<String> departNames = JsonPath.read(json, "$..departName");
String firstDepartName = JsonPath.read(json, "$..departName[0]");
```

Since this is json tree parsing and traversing engine, I strongly suspect that it will be less performant than Jackson (would be worth testing) but this gives you plenty other opportunities to flexibly process json strings.